# Existence of certain graph gadget related to coloring odd hole free graph

Tags: graph-theory, graph-colouring

Crossposted from [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/211209/existence-of-certain-graph-gadget-related-to-coloring-odd-hole-free-graph).

Wondering about the existence of graph gadget related to coloring
(or 3-coloring) odd hole free graphs.

Let $G$ be simple $k$-chromatic connected graph with two
vertices $u,v$.

Is it possible $G$ to satisfy:

1. All **induced** $uv$ paths have odd order (even number of
   edges).
2. In all proper $k$ colorings, $u$ and $v$ have distinct colors
3. (optional) $G$ doesn't contain induced $C_{2n+1}$ for $n>1$

If this is possible, there is reduction $F$ to odd hole free $F'$.

Replace an edge $u'v'$ by the gadget $G$ where $u'=u,v'=v$ and the
rest vertices of $G$ are new vertices.

According to graphclasses coloring odd hole free is NP hard
and 3-coloring is unknown.

Computer search suggest small gadgets don't exist (modulo errors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One can extract an argument that this cannot work from the paper [found by OP in the MO thread](http://www.ime.usp.br/~cris/gcomb/pronex/ps-dvi-files/celina/livro.ps.gz). Suppose $G=(V,E)$ is as required, and $c:V\to[k]$ is a $k$-coloring. By the assumption, $c(u)\neq c(v)$. Consider the (bipartite) subgraph $H$ induced by $\{x\in V\ |\ c(x)\in\{c(u),c(v)\}\}$.

If $u$ and $v$ are in the same connected component of $H$, pick any shortest path in $H$ between $u$ and $v$; it is an induced path in $G$, with colors alternating between $c(u),c(v)$, and must have an odd number of edges because the colors at its ends differ. This contradicts the assumption.

So $u,v$ are in different connected components; but then one can toggle the coloring of one of these components to obtain a coloring $c'$ with $c'(u)=c'(v)$, contradiction.

Comment: Thank you. I allow induced triangles in all cases, does your answer still apply?

Comment: Check the MO comments about "even pairs" and "merging even pairs preserves the chromatic number", this might disprove it.

Comment: reverse image - I have updated to get rid of it (and deleted some obsolete comments)

Comment: Are you saying that if $u,v$ is an even pair, in all colorings $c(u)=c(v)$? I believe this follows from preserving the chromatic number when merging $u,v$.

Comment: Why non-existence of even path in the bipartite subgraph means no such in the WHOLE graph? A path may pass thru a vertex outside the bipartite graph or am I missing something?

Comment: The argument merely says that from any given coloring, we can get another where $u,v$ have the same color, contradicting the assumption that their colors always differ. And we don't have to show non-existence of an even path, just existence of an odd (induced) one.

Comment: Oh, I see now (misunderstood before). This proof is likely correct.

Comment: Your proof shows: if $u,v$ is even pair, in some proper coloring $u,v$ have the same color, right?

Comment: Yes, that is it in a nutshell.